C# - Problema con TextBox de atributo Date - Control de Hora
como estan?
Me estoy volviendo loco con este tema y necesito su apoyo. Estoy trabajando en C#, tengo un Textbox con un atributo Time, para que se muestre la hora de inicio de una Consulta Medica.
Tengo un objeto "Consulta" que tiene un atributo de tipo String que es hora_inicio, cuando quiero cargar los datos de esa consulta en el Textbox es cuando tengo el problema.
Creo que es un problema con el postback, cuando selecciono la Consulta que quiero ver, se pone por un segundo la hora de inicio correcta, pero automaticamente vuelve a cambiarse a la hora actual. Probe varias cosas, como cargar la hora de inicio en una Session y cargarla desde alli luego del postback, pero nada funciona.
Mi HTML es el siguiente:
<asp:TextBox ID="txtHoraInicio" runat="server" class="u-input u-input-rectangle" Visible="False" EnableViewState="True" ></asp:TextBox>

Mi PageLoad es el siguiente:
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        txtHoraInicio.Attributes.Add("Type", "Time");
    }
    else
    {
        
    }
}

Cuando cargo el valor en txtHoraInicio lo hago de la siguiente manera:
 txtHoraInicio.Text = unaConsulta.Hora_inicio;

Ya no se por donde mas arrancar, si le saco el atributo de tipo Time, se carga correctamente la hora.
Ideas?
Muchas Gracias!

El código que has agregado es insuficiente para detectar el problema. Debes [edit] tu pregunta y agregar un [MCVE], esto es un código que yo pueda copiar/pegar y al ejecutarlo vea el mismo problema que tu describes. Este código debe estar libre de otras piezas de código que no aportan a la pregunta (es ruido)

Si estás cargando un valor en un TextBox que tiene EnableViewState en True, y luego se produce un postback, el valor del ViewState puede sobrescribir el valor que le has asignado. Prueba a deshabilitar el ViewState para ese TextBox:
<asp:TextBox ID="txtHoraInicio" runat="server" class="u-input u-input-rectangle" Visible="False" EnableViewState="False"></asp:TextBox>

